# Update and delete Outlook appointment

Tags: c#, outlook

Need logical flow for Creating, Updating and Deleting Outlook Appointment

I am able to create appointment in Outlook using c#, but now i want to update or delete the appointment using C#.

Did i have to use EntryId.

But how to update or delete using this
or suggest me the correct way of updating and deleting the appointment.

Comment: How did you create the appointment? Did you use the Exchange API web services?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Comment: were you able to solve your problem, I have completed all operations on outlook using c# and microsoft.office.interop.outlook. May b I can help you.

Comment: Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitem_methods%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem has a Delete method and a Save method.

See: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitem_methods(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitem_methods%28v=office.14%29.aspx)